# How can I register app with * in the name for the event log?

Tags: c++, winapi, event-log

I'm trying to register my Windows local service that has an asterisk (*) in the name in the event log. I follow instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then the call to [RegisterEventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with that name succeeds and events are logged OK, but when I try to view them in the Windows Event Viewer all my entries have the following attached to them:

> The description for event ID for source App*Name could not be found.

This happens only on OS earlier than Windows 7. Also if I remove the asterisk everything works OK.

Any idea how to fix this? Well, besides dropping the asterisk from the app name :)